# Excel Translation of Dates Different From One Spreadsheet to Another

Tags: excel, date

This has me baffled.  I have a program that copies cells from one Excel 2013 spreadsheet into a new Excel 2013 spreadsheet.  Dates are not showing the same when copied.  I narrowed it down to this:  the source cell format is mm/dd/yy and for example displays 07/01/16.  When this is copied to the new spreadsheet it displays as 06/30/12.  Changing the format of source and destination cells to number format reveals the true value of 41090, which I know should be 06/30/2012.  What could be making the source spreadsheet interpret 41090 as the date 07/01/2016?  If it makes a difference, the source spreadsheet data was manally entered into columns preformatted as date mm/dd/yy, and the example entry was entered as 07/01/16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is the difference between the 1900 and 1904 date systems. You can read about it in this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/214330). There is a difference of 1,462 between your dates and the dates mentioned in the article. Furthermore, the article will explain problems copying dates between workbooks and how to change the date system in Excel. For 2013 it is (`File` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `When calculating this workbook`).

Comment: Yes, that was it.  Thank you.

Comment: @KennethBerg No problem! Glad it helped! Could you mark as correct? :)

Comment: Quick correct answer to my question.